# Fact-check: Has the US increased imports of Russian oil?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, sanctions, oil, fact-check-request

There have been reports that the US has increased imports of Russian oil over the past week:

- [US ramps up oil imports from Russia, pursues own interests at expense of European allies amid Ukraine crisis](https://www.globaltimes.cn/page/202204/1257500.shtml)
- [US increases oil imports from Russia by 43% : Russian Official](https://www.aninews.in/news/world/europe/us-increases-oil-imports-from-russia-by-43-russian-official20220403224201/)
- [US Increases Imports of Russian Oil by 43% In the Last Week](https://www.telesurenglish.net/news/US-Increases-Imports-of-Russian-Oil-by-43-In-the-Last-Week-20220403-0005.html)

This goes contrary to the US's stated intention of phasing out Russian oil imports and stories like that of [the Russian tanker turned back](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/02/climate/oil-tankers-russia.html?unlocked_article_code=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACEIPuomT1JKd6J17Vw1cRCfTTMQmqxCdw_PIxftm3iWka3DJDm4YiO8RAo2J50qKYqtnIsc62TeWXsQEKqI0X_17iO9DOkgnAy-Znqy5orVXaSMktdD0GWosw5PGWb1__Ta7MGCzd7k6nLHg4FfbPmW6RK3a1SE-IglmqJtnJg37iXAP1b6FRrAuoqR23fkhDpB_Rz0KdXPK66GuU0MiTY3AOhLM6QA2WPVbXCXRm7Of77EDeAZVCzHWXS81oDZ8uJ4HZoRhbOuoJAUgecH-nbwWFmVtSY-uDJU6TITV_K54c-AD8ejQK-mXJYNTXSSJlg&smid=url-share). However, the sources cited above are not what I would call mainstream and they reference statements made by Russian officials. Thus, the question arises of whether these reports are true or not. I see three possibilities:

1. The reports of the US increasing import of Russian oil are large-scale disinformation
2. The US has increased Russian oil imports as a way to finish its existing contracts with Russian oil producers before the deadline imposed by the sanctions.
3. The US is playing [Realpolitik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realpolitik) - pursuing its own interests both in terms of imposing sanctions and pushing down the fuel prices.

I am interested in confirming/disproving these reports using official government data, customs statistics, etc.

Comment: When one sees a statement like this in any context, one should ask oneself a few questions: 1. What are the absolute numbers? ("US bought 7 barrels this week, up from 5 last week!") 2. What is the size of the average fluctuations over time intervals of the size measured (US buys 43% more oil than last week, which was 80% less oil than the week before!") 3. Are there any periodic trends ("US imports increased 43% in April over March, unlike last year when they increased 100%!")

Comment: @Obie2.0 Following up the links could help ;) They claim 43% is 100,000 barrels a day.

Comment: Even if those particular articles address it, all those points are still relevant with regard to maintaining skepticism about "percent increase" claims.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Sure, please include them in your answer, just make sure to use reliable sources. As I stated: *I am interested in confirming/disproving these reports using official government data, customs statistics, etc.*

Comment: @Obie2.0 I think misrepresentation of *precent increase* would fall under my first bullet. Please take no offense: the points you made are all valid... but I am rather amused when someone lectures me about the importance of numbers, statistics, etc. - I also have quantitative background ;)

Comment: There's an almost identical question in Skeptics.SE: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53174/did-the-usa-increase-oil-imports-from-russia-after-the-ukraine-invasion

Comment: It should be noted that the question on Skeptics has some good details in the answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sort of - this claim is based on the [figures published weekly](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_move_wimpc_s1_w.htm) by the Energy Information Administration. For the week of 03/25/22, the US imported 100,000 barrels per day, up from 70,000 barrels per day the week before. This is indeed an increase of around 43%.

On the other hand, compared to the four-week average from last year, this is a decrease of around 30%, from 127,000 barrels per day to 89,000 per day. Additionally, the figures for the week of 04/01/22 - published after my initial answer was posted - show a 100% fall down to zero barrels for that week. This data is also shown in graph form below - the claim in your question is based on the final up-tick on the right-hand side of the graph before it drops to zero.

Futhermore, President Biden's [executive order of March 8th, 2022](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2022/03/08/executive-order-on-prohibiting-certain-imports-and-new-investments-with-respect-to-continued-russian-federation-efforts-to-undermine-the-sovereignty-and-territorial-integrity-of-ukraine/) prohibits all oil imports from Russia, although transactions related to contracts entered into prior to this date have been authorised by a General License issued by the Treasury up until [April 22nd](https://home.treasury.gov/system/files/126/russia_gl16.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now I am not even sure that it was a deliberately misleading statement - perhaps simply media looking for a cheap sensation.

Comment: @RogerVadim that is usually the case. It's easy to manipulate numbers to say anything that you want. A famous phrase goes: 'There are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and statistics.'

Comment: The famous phrase is for those not understanding statistics. In this particular case, the ~40% increase week to week is pretty much normal given the graph above and cannot be considered significant.

Comment: Could it be that oil arrives in tankers, and one single tanker is 40% of average weekly imports? So with five tankers arriving every two weeks, you'd have to have 40% week over week changes all the time?

Comment: @RogerVadim "deliberately misleading statement" is still true, even if the motivation is just profit rather than political.

Comment: @barbecue They say that CIA defines *black lie* as saying untruth, and *white lie* as saying truth that would be incorrectly understood. So something can be true, but still a lie.

Comment: @RogerVadim I am not sure if the CIA is a good source to be quoting for that.

Comment: It is worth noting that a negligible share of U.S. oil consumption is derived from Russian imports and that this has been the case for some time. Further, a big share of U.S. imports of Russian petroleum products in pre-Ukraine War times are low grade "heavy" products not used, for example, as a source from which to refine gasoline.